# Anchor link to FAQs on product page

Tags: e-commerce, faq, anchors

I'm currently improving the accessibility of the FAQ on our product page after some feedback from the business that the FAQ might be too low on the page for users to engage with. This is a rough layout of our product page:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE4Vt.png]

After looking through some browsing sessions, users are engaging more with the FAQ than all the marketing-driven USPs above it. Now, i've looked around and it's fairly common for the FAQ to be at the bottom of the page - so instead of moving it around and breaking the 'flow' of the page, i'm thinking of adding an anchor link somewhere near the top to prevent users from having to scroll through so much stuff to reach the FAQ.

My question is, assuming that the anchor links are the right way to do this, what would be the optimal position to place an FAQ anchor link on this page?

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE Horramcha, you'd better if you include full forms of abbreviations used in your questions, so that people trying to understand have a clearer understanding regardless of their sector. FAQ might be clear but words like USP not really widely common words to be comprehended without searching/checking for everyone.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly the answer you're looking for, but can't you simply collapse the Delivery & Warranty USP, Product Details, USP+Content Blocks and Review sections within an accordion? That way, the user would be able to interact with the section they want to learn more about and reach FAQs relatively quickly.

Comment: Unfortunately that would require a significant amount of dev effort that we don't really have for this particular task - we'd like to test out some more incremental changes prior to making a bigger sweeping change like you suggested (not that I don't agree, but it's a matter of feasibility for me at this point).

Comment: Are the questions driven by users or are they pre-defined in nature? That is, if I were to visit a PDP, would I see questions posted by users, or would it be a bunch of pre-defined questions posted by the platform or the seller?

Comment: Have you tried adding links to the Reviews and FAQs within the product form? Something similar to the way Amazon links to its reviews section. Have a look at how products similar to yours solve the problem. Amazon and eBay are usually good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, FAQ could be connected to Product details section. So you could have under that section something like "Still didnt find all info you need? Visit our Faq section".

Answer (score 0):

You should place it in the right context, meaning where users would think that their current issue might be solved within the FAQ questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would place this underneath the product details section, as you're providing navigation to the content speciifically related to this, and it also makes logical sense for this to be high up the page so that users can avoid unnecessary scrolling.

You *could* provide anchor links to all the content sections, not just the FAQ's, so users know early on what the page content is and can skip to what they need.

Alternatively, you could provide some kind of tab layout, with a navigation below the product details, to let users click through to what they want, and easily switch between sections without much needed scrolling. This is something we implemented on our e-commerce site and it had much more success than a long layout, which had a lot of drop off on heatmaps.